# Interpreting large coefficient values in Poisson regression

Tags: poisson-distribution, random-effects-model, poisson-regression

I'm running a Poisson regression using proc glimmix (log link) with the outcome of count of events in each month and an explanatory variable. The explanatory variable has a coefficient value of 3.3. If I want to convert this value to a % change (e.g., one unit increase in explanatory variable is associated with a X % change in the outcome), I am getting this:

100*(exp(3.3)-1) = 2611.264%

This seems like an extremely large % change. Some of the other models I run yield smaller coefficient (e.g., <0.05) but in this particular case I'm wondering how to interpret such a large % change.

Comment: Is this a dummy input?

Comment: The outcome is a count and the explanatory variable is coded 1/0 and not in the class statement, so yes, it would be a dummy input.

Comment: You may not have a problem at all. What “other models” have you run?